# Growing data.table row by row each time time by different amount

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering why this code does not simply concatenate the two data frames.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2))

df <- vector("list", 2)
df[[1]] <- as.list(data.frame(b=c('a','b','c', 'd'), 
                              c=c(11, 22, 33, 99), 
                              z=c('aa','bb','cc', 'dd')))
df[[2]] <- as.list(data.frame(b=c('b','e', 'f', 'g'),
                              c=c(44,55,66,77), 
                              z=c('gg','bb','hh', 'dd')))   
getData <- function(i) {
  return(df[[i]])
}

dt <- dt[, getData(a), by=a]
print(dt)
```

I was expecting a result as follows:

```
   a b  c  z
1: 1 a 11 aa
2: 1 b 22 bb
3: 1 c 33 cc
4: 1 d 99 dd
5: 2 b 44 gg
6: 2 e 55 bb
7: 2 f 66 hh
8: 2 g 77 dd
```

But I get the following:

```
   a b  c  z
1: 1 a 11 aa
2: 1 b 22 bb
3: 1 c 33 cc
4: 1 d 99 dd
5: 2 a 44 cc
6: 2 b 55 aa
7: 2 c 66 dd
8: 2 d 77 bb
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the definition of `df$a` like this:

```
df[[1]] <- as.list(data.frame(a=1,
                              b=c('a','b','c', 'd'), 
                              c=c(11, 22, 33, 99), 
                              z=c('aa','bb','cc', 'dd'))) 

df[[2]] <- as.list(data.frame(a=2,
                                  b=c('b','e', 'f', 'g'),
                                  c=c(44,55,66,77), 
                                  z=c('gg','bb','hh', 'dd')))
```

I believe all you need to do to accomplish this is use `rbindlist()`, like so:

```
> result <- rbindlist(df)
> result
   a b  c  z
1: 1 a 11 aa
2: 1 b 22 bb
3: 1 c 33 cc
4: 1 d 99 dd
5: 2 b 44 gg
6: 2 e 55 bb
7: 2 f 66 hh
8: 2 g 77 dd
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact for my application, the smaller data.frames are NOT known in advance. getData function reads them from files and they may contain different rows, although the columns are fixed. Could you please show how to use rbindlist in that case?

Comment: I would need more specifics on how you're reading in your data, and what your data looks like.  Why are you storing the individual columns as list items?  why not just un-wrap `df[[1]]` and `df[[2]]` from the `as.list()` function?

Comment: I solved my problem using your idea as follows:

`getData2 <- function(dt) {
  return(df[[dt[1,a]]])
}

newDt<-rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(x) { getData2(dt[x])}))
print(newDt)`

Comment: Thank you. However, just wondering why previous attempt using `getData` did not work.

Comment: @Soumitra It's because you are using factors. Unlike `rbind.data.frame` and `rbindlist`,  `DT[...]` doesn't go out of its way to make your column attributes consistent across `by=` groups. Another example: `data.table(x = 1:2)[, factor(letters[x]), by=x]`. Open issue about it: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2522